# Scrape all the pages of a website when next page's follow-up link is not available in the current page source code

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi i have successfully scraped all the pages of few shopping websites by using Python and Regular Expression.
But now i am in trouble to scrape all the pages of a particular website where next page follow up link is not present in current page like this one here http://www.jabong.com/men/clothing/mens-jeans/

This website is loading the next pages data in same page dynamically by Ajax calls. So while scraping i am only able to scrape the data of First page only. But I need to scrape all the items present in all pages of that website.

I am not getting a way to get the source code of all the pages of these type of websites where next page's follow up link is not available in Current page. Please help me through this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site is using AJAX requests to get more search results as the user scrolls down.  The initial set of search results can be found in the main request:

http://www.jabong.com/men/clothing/mens-jeans/

As the user scrolls down the page detects when they reach the end of the current set of results, and loads the next set, as needed:

http://www.jabong.com/men/clothing/mens-jeans/?page=2

One approach would be to simply keep requesting subsequent pages till you find a page with no results.

By the way, I was able to determine this by using the proxy tool in screen-scraper.  You could also use a tool like Charles or HttpFox.  They key is to browse the site and watch what HTTP requests get made so that you can mimic them in your code.

Comment: have u tried the link http://www.jabong.com/men/clothing/mens-jeans/?page=2 in your browser it dosent works. They are very smart although your this technique of appending page no at the end works in some of websites but here it dosent work